# Does knowledge about value length compromise hash integrity

Tags: database, security, encryption, hash

If I am storing a hashed value in a database, but the length of the original value being hashed is fixed (eg. always 4 characters), does this compromise the one-way nature of the hashing function?

More precisely,  I have sensitive strings which I then encrypt and store in a database.  In order to search for these strings, I don't want to decrypt every entry in the database, so I also store the hash of the first 4 characters of the string in another column.  When I want to search the database I generate the hash of the first 4 characters of the search term and compare it to the stored hashes to find which entries match or could match and then decrypt those entries to check for collisions and get the rest of the data related to that entry.

My worry is that since an attacker would know that the length of the strings being hashed is constant (4 characters), he/she would only need to generate a table of all possible 4 letter strings and their hashes and look-up the hashed values stored in my database (thereby giving away the first 4 characters of the original sensitive string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty much right in your conclusion.  If an attacker knows that your hash is of a 4 character string, it's pretty trivial to find the plain text via brute force.  In addition to giving the attacker knowledge of first 4 characters of your sensitive data, it could also allow them to gain knowledge of part of the key you are using to encrypt your data (on a simple level encryption is key XOR plaintext, that means plaintext XOR encrypted = key).  While it would be challenging to use that information to break the rest of the encryption, cryptographic attacks have been build on less.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of search you want to perform there are a couple options you may use to improve upon your scheme:

1. Search for full strings: You could encrypt the search term and query on that. Or store the hash of the encrypted string, and query on that if your strings are very long.
2. Search for partial strings: Alter your scheme by using a keyed hash instead of a simple hash.